# Is there any official formatting for the URL fragment?

Tags: javascript, html, css, deep-linking, url-fragment

In the project I'm working on part the URL fragment is used to update the view. But if the view is updated by the URL fragment the vertical anchor position is lost.

Is there an official way to format a URL fragment to contain a view and anchor? Or does the browser already have support for something like what I'm asking about?

If not is there any reason not to use something like the following?

**Example**

Current Standard Fragment
`https://www.example.com/page.html#anchorOnThePage`
Goes to the page and then scrolls into view an anchor named `anchorOnThePage`

Current with SPA or PWA:
`https://www.example.com/page.html#view1`
Goes to the page and then displays a view named `view1`

Desired:
`https://www.example.com/page.html#view1:anchorOnThePage`
Goes to the page and then displays a view named `view1` and then scrolls into view `anchorOnThePage`.

Feedback is welcome but for the time being the hash fragment is primarily what I have to work with.

I could use something like this:
`https://www.example.com/page.html#view=view1&anchor=anchorOnThePage`
`https://www.example.com/page.html#view:view1&anchor:anchorOnThePage`

But it might look cleaner with a simple separator like a colon or period, go to the view (first index) and then go to the anchor if it exists (second index).
`https://www.example.com/page.html#view1:anchorOnThePage`
`https://www.example.com/page.html#view1.anchorOnThePage`

**Update**:

I would like to use path more and there was a recommendation about this a while ago I think in Google's deep linking guide.

The suggestion was something like this `http://www.example.com/page.html/view/post/id/101`. I think WordPress does this.

BUT someone made a fuss about it and they dropped it. I don't remember all the details hence this post.

Comment: Here you have an exact explanation of what you can and can't do in the url - [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13500078/10424385)

Comment: Likely the view should be part of the path and not the anchor

Comment: @djfdev How would you make it part of the path?